# RxJs : How to rethrow error from observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to RxJS. Learning observables and subjects.
I have a very simple login code divided into two files, a) auth.service.ts and b) login.component.ts

Here is login.component.ts

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
const reqBody = {
  "userName": username,
  "password": password
};
const body = JSON.stringify(reqBody);
const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
this.httpClient.post<IAuthToken>(this.apiUrl, body, { 'headers': headers })
  .subscribe(response => {
    if (response) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.accessTokenKey, response.access_token);
      subject.next(true);
    }
    else {
      throwError("Login request failed. Please try again later");
    }
  },
    error => {
      // TODO : Code to show invalid username password
      // this code throws error. Subscribe in the login.component.ts doesnt receive any error.
      throwError(error.error);
    });
return subject.asObservable();
```

}

Here is login.component.ts code

```
errorMsg: string;
constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthService
  ) {  }
async onLogin(): Promise<void> {
   
         
        this.authenticationService.login(this.loginForm.value.username,
          this.loginForm.value.password)
          .subscribe((response) => {
            this.errorMsg = null;
            if (response)
                 console.log("logged In");
          },
            error => {
              // TODO : Code to show invalid username password
              // This code doesnt execute, i.e. error is not caught.
              this.errorMsg = error.error;
              console.log(error);
            });
    }
  }
```

I want to throw error for invalid username password from auth.service.ts and catch it in login.component.ts so that can bind the error to UI.
However, the throwError throws error from auth.service.ts, but the error isnt caught in login.component.html

Answer (score 4):

Several misconceptions here.

Firstly, `throwError` is a function which returns an observable that immediately errors. Simply calling it like you do doesn't do anything.

```
throwError(error.error); // creates an unused observable
```

Secondly, you're subscribing in the service with some weird glued-together code with a subject. Your service is supposed to just create an observable, and then you subscribe to it in the component. The error would then be caught correctly by default.

```
// in service
logIn (username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.post(api, { username, password })
    .pipe(mapTo(true))
}

// in component
onSubmit () {
  this.service.logIn('username', 'p@ssword')
    .subscribe({
      next: () => {
        console.log('Success!')
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error(error)
      }
    })
}
```

---

`throwError` is usually used in conjuction with `catchError` when you want to propagate *some* errors and handle *some* errors.

```
return this.http.post(api, { username, password })
  .pipe(
     catchError((error) => {
       if (canHandleError(error)) {
         // handle...
         return of(false)
       } else {
         return throwError(error)
       }
     }),
  )
```

Comment: The above code makes sense. However, I want to write the token into localstorage from auth.service.ts. So,  before returning true from the mapto function, how can i write token?

Answer (score 1):

No need to subscribe in service

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    const reqBody = {
        "userName": username,
        "password": password
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify(reqBody);
    return this.httpClient.post<IAuthToken>(this.apiUrl, body, { 'headers': headers })
        .pipe(map(response => {
            if (response) {
                localStorage.setItem(this.accessTokenKey, response.access_token);
                return true;
            }
        }))
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to do side effects in the `map` operator. It makes your code more difficult to understand because it abuses the power of functions. You should use a `tap` instead to write into local storage. Furthermore, the function passed to `map` now returns `true | undefined`, which doesn't adhere to the contract defined in the method signature (`Observable<boolean>`).